# glMapBuffer Returns 0x00000000 constantly

Tags: opengl, vbo, vertex, vertex-buffer

I have initialized glewInit( ) and any other openGL stuff. all before i do any of these calls.

```
  glGenBuffers( 1, &m_uiVertBufferHandle );
  glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_uiVertBufferHandle );
  glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 0, GL_READ_WRITE );
  glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0 );
```

this is how i create my buffer object i i did the glBufferData because i have read in openGL articles that you do not have any storage space at all if you do not call it at least once which would make glMapBuffer always give you 0x00000000.

later on i call glMapBuffer to get my storage location to start saving data 
when i use glMapBuffer i call it like this

```
void* buffer1; 
glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m_uiVertBufferHandle );

//make sure our buffer excists
buffer1 = glMapBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_READ_WRITE );
```

i always get 0x00000000 in my buffer1. Why is this? the only 2 causes i have found at all were that i didn't initialize glewInit properly which i have done and that i wasnt calling glBindBufferData at least once.

Comment: The solution to [not getting answers you like](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281508/glmapbuffer-returns-0x00000000-constantly) is not to delete your old question and asking it again. Just FYI.

Comment: @NicolBolas Depends on if someone has abused the system with their answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, 0, GL_READ_WRITE );
```

`GL_READ_WRITE` is [not a valid usage for buffer objects](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBufferData). You use that for *mapping*, not the buffer object's usage. Usage parameters are stuff like `GL_STATIC_DRAW`, or more reasonably for your "read/write" case, `GL_DYNAMIC_READ`.

Because you passed an invalid enum, OpenGL gave you a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` error and failed to execute this command. Also, 0 length buffer object is not a reasonable size for the buffer's storage. Try `new int[0]` or `malloc(0)` sometime and see what happens.

Please stop [allocating miniscule or non-existent sizes of data.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13281508/glmapbuffer-returns-0x00000000-constantly) Allocate 4096 bytes or something if you really want to test this.

Comment: YES!! thank you so much :D. so many enums and enums that sound similiar and enums that are for the same function with a slight change in wording O_O. thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You pass `0` as the size of the buffer  into `glBufferData`. This means that OpenGL implementation does not know the size (even theoretical) of your buffer and does not know how to map this zero-sized buffer.

Use non-zero value as the size and NULL as the data pointer, i.e:

```
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, SizeOfTheBuffer, NULL, GL_READ_WRITE );
```

**P.S.** `GL_READ_WRITE` is not a valid usage for buffer objects.

Comment: i changed it to
glBufferData( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(int), NULL, GL_READ_WRITE );

im just trying to create my storage space to start off. just so i can have my buffer object storage space.

i tried doing what you said by putting some sort of size im still getting 0x00000000 for my void* buffer1

Comment: GL_READ_WRITE is not a valid usage for buffer objects.